# Can I register functions in an event and THEN check if conditions are met?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I would like to create an Event Manager of some kind that is constantly checking for conditions, but I would like to be able to add functions with a return value.

Unity has UnityEvents, which are functions activated when certain conditions are met: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYLNo.jpg

I would like to be able to modify **the conditions**.

Example in pseudocode:

Boy A and Boy B are CPersons:

```
CPerson

bool _isAlive

public bool IsAlive(){
return _isAlive
}
```

There's an Area Trigger, whenever Player enters, return true

```
CAreaTrigger

bool _triggered

void OnTriggerEnter(){
_triggered = true;
}

public bool IsTriggered(){
return _triggered;
}
```

I would like my Event Manager to be able to do this:

```
If (boyA.IsAlive() && AreaTrigger.IsTriggered())
{
WIN
}

If (!boyA.IsAlive())
{
LOSE
}
```

...but *without* writing that code for each case. In essence, something like this:

```
If (Conditions are met)
{
WIN
}

If (One losing condition is met)
{
LOSE
}
```

Is there any way to do this, to set up functions and listen if they return a certain value?

Comment: `Conditions are met` and `One losing condition is met` = `Func<bool>`

Comment: @eurotrash yeah, but is there any way I could add those functions in the Editor? To be able to create different levels with different Win and Lose conditions, without having to create a different script for every stage.

Comment: I know nothing about Unity, but if you have an "event manager" and you want it to do some unknown checks and take some predefined action, you can make the manager take a `Func<bool>` for its generic check and then pass it `() => boyA.IsAlive() && AreaTrigger.IsTriggered()` or whatever. Or if you also want to have it execute an unknown action, then take an `Action` and supply full delegate including the action taken if the `if` statement succeeds. Or am I misunderstanding your question?